# Keyboard software problems

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, lag

My keyboard (Microsoft Digital Media Pro Keyboard) lags on random and frequent occasions. for example, if I'll press and hold 'u' the output would be "uuuuuuuuuuu"...gets frozen...and then the rest of the 'u's will apear in a sudden fashion.
note that this lag doesn't occur only when I press and hold a key, it can affect any sort of input from the keyboard (and it's timings seem random).

what I've tried so far:

- The mouse responds while the lag occurs. (means that only the keyboard gets frozen and not the whole system)
- I've connected another keyboard and the lag didnt go away. (means it's probably a software problem)
- Uninstalled and installed the driver
- Cleaned about 50 GB out of 300GB (been below that for a while, and it didnt seem to bother anything)
- Used defraggler to defrag the HD
- Ordered Avast to do a virus scan, it didnt find anything.
- Used Eusing to clean any registry problems (showed above 2000)
- And I've used Western Digital's data lifeguard diagnostic, to check if the HD is ok

to sum up,I prefer to find a solution other than formatting. 
I have no leads and I must fix this.
any helpfull comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you messed up characterer repetition delays? does your bios contain such feature? if not, check it under keyboard properties in control panel.

Comment: character repeat delay is set to "shortest", and the repeat rate is set to "fastest" the lag doesnt occur only while holding a key, even if youll spam asdfasfasdf or just use the arrow keys, the lag will apear randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after I've uninstalled old java updates like it says here:
[Keyboard Lag & Slow Typing Solution](http://www.pchelpforum.com/xf/threads/keyboard-software-problems.150306/)